# Translating PromQL 'sum(rate(value))' queries to InfluxQL

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, influxdb, influxql

I'm creating a custom k8s grafana dashboard with datasource as InfluxDB (v1.8.6).I have gone through the influxdb documentation and recognised that the analogical construct for **prometheus rate()** in influx is **non_negative_derivative(mean(value), interval)**. But on trying to convert the prometheus query to InfluxQL, the resultant query values vary when executed against same time intervals. Im basically trying to compute the k8s cluster network i/o pressure.

**PromQL** :

`sum (rate (container_network_receive_bytes_total{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$", job="kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor"}[1m]))`

Output is in bytes : 7321180

**InfluxQL** :

`SELECT  SUM(bytes_used) FROM (SELECT non_negative_derivative(mean(value), 1s) AS bytes_used FROM container_network_receive_bytes_total WHERE ("job" = 'kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor' AND "kubernetes_io_hostname" =~ /^$Node$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1m)) group by time($__interval)`

Output is in Mb/s : 36.7 MB/s

Could someone help identify the issue and correct me ?